# Проблема с расположением элементов в карточке

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Нужно расположить текст в карточке в разных краях, в зависимости от заполнения. Вроде бы сделал все правильно, заголовок и текст вынес в отдельный блок и задал ему

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
jusctify-content: space-between;
```

по сути, они должны были разделиться и иметь хоть какое либо расстояние между собой, но этого не происходит.
У третьей и четвертой карточки на макете есть расстояние между текстом и заголовком, но на деле никакого расстояния нет
[image: фото макета]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное, всё же `justify-content`, а не `jusctify-content`.

Comment: Это опечатка только тут, в vs code все в порядке

Comment: Если первое фото - это макет, то здесь нужен не `space-between`, иначе третья карточка выглядела бы по-другому. Судя по макету, для блоков с заголовками высота задана жёстко (например, в пикселях).